# accessing precise integral variable's value through c++

Tags: c++, solution, cplex

cplex.getvalue(x) return float value, and when I put the value in int, it's different from the initial one. Is there a better way to accessing the integer variable's value?

Now I just use a naive way and I don't know whether it's right or not

```
val = cplex.getObjValue() + 0.1;

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   returnX[i] = cplex.getValue(x[i]) + 0.1;
```

Comment: What are you thinking the `0.1` does here? I assume that is your "naive way".

Comment: I'm not even sure what it is you are trying to accomplish with this

Comment: I know I should use 0.5, but ... I don't know why I use 0.1

Answer (score 3):

If you store a floating point value in an integral type (such as `int`), you are going to lose any precision after the decimal point. Integral types simply only store integers. If you store a `float` in an `int`, you will lose anything after the decimal point.

If you add 0.1 to a `float`, you simply get a floating point value approximately 0.1 greater than the original value. If you assign that to an `int`, you'll have exactly the same problem. You're just going to truncate a different value.

If you need a `float` to retain its precision, simply store it in a `float` (or a `double` for even higher precision).

If perhaps you are doing a conversion like `int -> float -> int` where the original `int` is of one value and the value you get at the end is a different `int`, well that's just what happens. The conversion to a `float` is not symmetric. The `int` to `float` conversion will convert to the nearest representable `float` value, whereas the `float` to `int` conversion will truncate.

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. [...]
>
> A prvalue of an integer type or of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of a floating point type. The result is exact if possible. If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but the value cannot be represented exactly, it is an implementation-defined choice of either the next lower or higher representable value. [...]

The solution to this is to not convert to an intermediate `float`. If you want an `int`, keep it an `int`. If for some reason it makes sense for your function to return a `float` despite the fact that the thing it calculate was an `int` then you have to accept the consequences.

Comment: As long as an `int` is within the number of bits that a `float` has (typically 23 bits, so about 8million definitely works, up to 16.2 million will probably work), nothing is lost (or gained) from storing it in `float`. But if some math is done to the float (adding, subtracting, multiplying or dividing) then the value may lose or gain bits, and thus no longer translate back to the original value, even if all the math should result in exactly the smae number.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of int and float, it's really good to know how the code actually works. Do you use cplex? Actually I think it should has the function to return the integer value directly.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you will lose precision value when casting it to int. You can do is round off the value.

**Example:**

```
float fVal = 10.89;

int nVal = (fVal > 0.0) ? (fVal + 0.5) : (fVal - 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because C++ rounds towards zero (instead of rounding to the nearest), and because floats store the *aproximate* value which may not be exactly accurate (e.g. 0.9999997f), then you get the results you are encountering.

Adding +0.001 is fine. If you're really wanting to round to the nearest, add 0.5f, and then let C++ round down to its heart's content.

```
float closerToFive = 5.454f;
float closerToSix = 5.545f;

int five = static_cast<int>(closerToFive + 0.5f);
int six = static_cast<int>(closerToSix + 0.5f);
```

Maybe it's a "naive way", but it works well. Wrap it in a func if you do it alot:

```
constexpr int ftoi(float value)
{
    return static_cast<int>(value + (value > 0.0f? 0.5f : -0.5f));
}


ftoi(5.454f) -> 5
ftoi(5.545f) -> 6
ftoi(-5.454f) -> -5
ftoi(-5.545f) -> -6
```

http://ideone.com/gDT4GP

**Edit:** Forgot to take into account negative floats, as CasperGhost's answer indicates. Fixed the ftoi() func.

Comment: Thanks very much, so there should be no problems with the naive way!

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I'm no expert on floating point math.